# Can "however" be immediately followed by an adverb?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am wondering if an adverb can be used after "however" when "however" is intended as "no matter how"? Because usually what comes immediately after "however" is an adjective. Is an adverb applicable in this case? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example: **However intelligently** he did his job, his boss never acknowledged it.

however=no matter how
I call it two adverbs in a row. Like "quite well" or "very bad"
One adverb can  modify another adverb.

The answer is yes.
[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/however#:%7E:text=However%20can%20be%20used%20in,could%20not%20control%20his%20feelings.)

> used for saying that it makes no difference how good, bad, difficult,
> etc. something is or how much there is of something
> **however good/well/bad/badly/hard etc.**:    She would still love him however badly he behaved.
>
> If you take money from the fund, however small the amount, you must
> record it in this book. however much/many: We’re determined to have a
> wonderful vacation, however much it costs.
>
> However many times you explain things, you can never get him to
> understand. however long something takes: We are determined to solve
> this problem, however long it takes.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are very welcome. :)

Comment: However fast you run, you will probably be caught by a police officer in a car.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, Michael, same idea. Your point? Why not a police officer on foot?